# JDatePicker object conversion to string

Tags: java, sql, swing, datepicker

I'm trying to implement jdatapicker in my swing application to input start date and end date to pass to sql query. Question is how to convert this datepicker object to string to pass to my query in yyyymmdd format.
Here is the implementation.

Date Formatter

```
    public class DateLabelFormatter extends AbstractFormatter {

    private String datePattern = "yyyymmdd";
    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new  SimpleDateFormat(datePattern);

    @Override
    public Object stringToValue(String text) throws ParseException {
        return dateFormatter.parseObject(text);
    }

    @Override
    public String valueToString(Object value) throws ParseException {
        if (value != null) {
            Calendar cal = (Calendar) value;
            return dateFormatter.format(cal.getTime());
        }

        return "";
      }

      }
```

DatePicker GUI
          class date {

```
         void GUI() {
        final JFrame f1 = new JFrame();
        f1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f1.setSize(300, 300);




        Container conn = f1.getContentPane();
        conn.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        UtilDateModel model = new UtilDateModel();
      //model.setDate(20,04,2014);
      // Need this...
      Properties p = new Properties();
      p.put("text.today", "Today");
      p.put("text.month", "Month");
      p.put("text.year", "Year");
      JDatePanelImpl datePanel = new JDatePanelImpl(model, p);
      // Don't know about the formatter, but there it is...
      final JDatePickerImpl datePicker = new JDatePickerImpl(datePanel, new               DateLabelFormatter());
      final JDatePickerImpl datePicker2=new JDatePickerImpl(datePanel, new DateLabelFormatter());

      final JTextField txt1=new JTextField();



      JButton button=new JButton("Click");
      button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
          JLabel label1=new JLabel();
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            txt1.setText("Testing");
            f1.add(label1);
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
       JLabel lbl_from=new JLabel("From ");
       JLabel lbl_to=new JLabel("To");
       f1.add(lbl_from);
       f1.add(datePicker);
       f1.add(lbl_to);
       f1.add(datePicker2);
       f1.add(button);
       f1.add(txt1);
       f1.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

calling in main()

```
            date d1 = new date();
            d1.GUI();
```

Comment: You don't, you make use of [Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) and wrap the `java.util.Date` in a `java.sql.Date` or `java.sql.Timestamp` and bind the value directly to the column ... assuming the data type of the column is a compatible "date"/"timestamp" type

Comment: then what will be the gui for user to input date? Would you please tell the implementation of JDatePicker in above case?

Comment: not necessarily JDatePicker, any other gui will be fine.

Comment: It doesn't really matter.  You get the `java.utill.Date` from the control, you wrap in a `java.sql.Date` and you insert that value into your database, you reverse the process when you want to get it back

Comment: feeling little confused. Actually I don't have hands on this before. 
Can you give me a demo to take date input from user?

Comment: Get the value from the `JDatePicker`, `java.util.Date date = (Date) datePicker.getModel().getValue();`, wrap this in a `java.sqk.Date`, `java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());`, now use a [Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) to bind the value to the required column and insert/update the database